# Totaling Function (Higher Order Function)

Tags: haskell

I need to define this function called total.

```
total :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
```

so that the total f is the function which at value n gives the sum
    f0 + f1 + .... + fn

Thanks for any help! Please.

---

According to the book as an example I found out about function composition that:

```
twice f = (f . f)
```

Here, f is a function, and the result is f composed with itself. For this to work, it needs to have the same input and output type. So we have

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

This states that twice takes one argument, a function of type (a -> a), and returns a result of the same type. For instance, if successor is the function to add one to an integer,

```
successor :: Int -> Int
successor n = n + 1     
then
(twice successor) 12 ->(successor . successor) 12 
-> successor (successor 12) -> 14
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Can you write a function that calculates the total of a specific function up to n? Can you write a function that totals all natural numbers up to n?

Comment: FYI, a "total function" is a function that is defined for all possible input values, in contrast to a "partial function". I took the freedom to edit your title accordingly to prevent confusion - what you are looking for is maybe a totaling function.

Comment: Yes @Ingo that's exactly what I am looking for. thanks! I am stuck at how to test the function and understand how it will work for other functions..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should be fine

```
total f n = sum [ f i | i <- [0..n] ]
```

However I guess you'll learn more if you define the function *recursively*. What should `total` at `n=0` return? Well: That's, by your definition `f 0`. I.e.

```
total f 0 = f 0
```

- Now what about `n=1`? That's `total f 1 = f 1 + total f 0 == f 1 + f 0`.
- For `n=2`: `total f 2 == f 2 + total f 1`.
- For `n` in general?

See the pattern? You can write this into plain Haskell.

Comment: True that, it makes more sense! :)

Answer (score 8):

An easy way would be:

```
total f 0 = f 0
total f n = total f (n-1) + f n
```

An alternative would be:

```
total f n = sum (map f [0..n])
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I test this in WinGHCi?

Comment: Type `let total f n = sum ...` and test e.g. by writing `total (\x -> x*x) 5`. For the pattern matching solution above, I recommend an extra file like `total.hs` which you just copy the source into and afterwards load into GHCi.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I didn't understand the test. What exactly happens when I run that? I got the result as 55.

Comment: It was Dario's test. And it sums the squares of the numbers from 1 to 5, i.e. 1+4+9+16+25 = 55.

Comment: Oh got it! So in place ot \x -> x*x I can input any other function and it will calculate it so. Thanks! I have another haskell problem, hoping you could help me with it, I am in a tight spot there too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700874/haskell-wordcount-function-counting-number-of-chars-words-lines-in-a-string